# How to gracefully quit after joining a new job within a week?

Tags: job-offer, career-development, job-change, united-kingdom, motivation

Basically I had two great opportunities one in a big research organisation and other from a fast paced startup. After some thought and a bit of intuition I though to join the first one but within couple of days I came to know that they don't take software development much seriously and the environment is a bit relaxed. They don't follow any code standard or style guide etc. maybe because the organisation has its main focus on research.
The environment is quite relaxed and so the reward/appraisal.

So, I am feeling a bit stuck because these are the things that you learn after joining only. On the other hand I am now actively looking at the Github repo of the startup and I feel that they are more into latest technology and fast paced development where I can learn much.

Its only couple of days since I joined here and I still have option to join the startup. What should I do? if I finally make my mind to join the startup then how should I quit from the current one? should I make up some family emergency situation?

PS: Both are from two different countries.

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause I don't think so.

Comment: Don't lie to an employer. *At best,* it won't harm you or your career aspirations now or in the future. *More likely,* it *will* come back to haunt you some time later, in some way shape or form.

Comment: @WorkerWithoutACause That Q&A mostly focuses on whether to take the job, not how to navigate actually quitting, and the fact that that involves education does change things a bit.

Comment: "What should I do?" is not a question we can answer for you, it's something you'll need to decide for yourself.

Comment: @Dukeling what should I do refers to what is the best way to handle the situation when I need to say no to the current employer in such a short duration.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I would agree to disagree. While hiring we are asked to solve difficult coding problems, face code reviews and if you pass theses then have to go through behavioural evaluation round. Do you really think the employee gets same privilege? also, are you sure the employer would tell me that they don't have any performance evaluation system or the manager itself doesn't encourage code reviews? yes, I learned these and many things after joining while taking to fellow employee and spending some time while looking his work.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am really amazed that most of the people think here that I am the culprit but in reality I am the one who is in loss i.e. loss of time, money and effort.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere and at last I am discussing it here because I am not a bad person and I am not strong enough to tell my senior that they are doing good.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I tried same for first company but their repos where private and since it is a public funded research organisation I thought it would be a stable but now I am thinking that I would be paying huge price for that stable position as you told everyone makes mistake and I did but now I want to correct that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I do?

I think you already made your mind about it.

> should I make up some family emergency situation?

No. Get the managers and talk to them about the situation. To me, it's quite straightforward. The way this company does software development is not aligned with your expectations and career aspirations.

Comment: My manager is on leave and he will come on Monday, I think it will be very unfortunate to discuss that in first meeting. Should I just write a mail?

Comment: I believe this topic will be better handled via a face to face conversation.

Comment: Also, the manager will want to know that you are leaving as soon as possible (but in a one-on-one meeting, if it is a general meeting wait until it is over)

Comment: Can't I mail my manager and just go away? since I know for sure a discussion would be embarrassing for both if use and anyways I am not going to change my decision also, he is a very busy person and mostly works from home or remains out of office.

Comment: At the end of the day it's your decision. Just keep in mind that it is not the most graceful way.

Answer (score 0):

Your job contract probably contains some kind of probation period during which quitting/firing is much easier/faster. Probationary periods are not just for the company to evaluate you but also for you to evalutate the company.

Of course people won't be happy if you leave considering the effort involved with hiring, but it's not something they should hold grudges over.

Check what your options for leaving are then make a polite resignation stating that the development department turned out to be very different from what you were expecting/looking for.

Comment: The other company may wait for at most a week I think. Should I expect them to release me within that time frame?

Comment: Only you can find out. We know neither your contract nor what country yo are working in. Though if I had to guess I'd say that there's a good chance you can quit within a week. My country has relatively long protection periods for quitting/firing and even here you can leave within a week during the probation period. And if both parties agree you can generally terminate the contract on the spot.

Comment: The current one is in UK.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too difficult to get out within a reasonable time frame (as explained by Kempeth), but I would like to add that if you are concerned about the other company not accepting you then you should communicate with them. I think it would be best to explain to them what has happened and ask for flexibility in the situation. You should express your definite commitment: make sure they know that you're not just keeping them on hold as a backup option but are serious about starting there.

In all you communication, remember to be candid, open and truthful. There is no better way to make this process arduous and difficult by muddying the waters with potential doubt about your integrity. you don't want either side of the table to think that you are taking them for a ride or being deliberately problematic, so make your intentions clear rather than trying to hide them behind something that you would consider a more 'reasonable excuse'.

And one final thing: engage in face to face communication over the matter whenever you can. I get that it's not always possible or convenient, but in my opinion it leads people to treat you more like a person than a company asset or resource. It shows that you are willing to open up and talk bout the situation honestly, and that should be seen as a good thing.

Comment: The joining date for next employer is anyways next week and I think I can ask for another week and they won't ask the reason having said that, I am more concerned about the current employer they may get confused or irritated on why they are not good etc. and how can I decide that on days time?

Comment: Again, be truthful. They may well be confused or irritated, but that's not your fault. If you are pressed for a reason, just tell them. You feel that the focus on software development and good software development practices is not strong enough for what you are comfortable with - if they are a reasonable employer, I would hope that they can accept these complaints without kicking up a fuss and maybe work on them in the future. Either way, you have your reasons and you can justify them. That should be all you need.